# Does uploading directly before render impact performance negatively?

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I have a vertex buffer that I update once a frame using glMapBufferRange and memcpy. Directly after updating, I call glDrawArrays.

A colleague of me says that it would be better to map/write/unmap the buffer at the beginning of the frame, then do other stuff in order to give the buffer time to upload, then call glDrawArrays as late as possible.

Is this claim true? I would think that anything that can cause a flush could trigger the upload burden, maybe at an even more inconvenient time than the actual render call.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, it shouldn't make any difference.

Rendering is already deeply asynchronous - you don't actually start drawing at the point you call `glDrawArrays()`, that just adds a command to a queue so the GPU shouldn't block immediately if there was a need for the data to upload.

For most modern hardware there is no actual data "upload" in either case - the memory system is coherent so you can see the data on the GPU as soon as unmap completes.

That said, there are benefits to CPU overhead in many cases to making fewer, larger, map/unmap calls so you might want to batch multiple buffer updates together in either case rather than doing them draw-by-draw.